# why is fgetc or fgets ignoring

Tags: c, file

Today I almost became crazy because the size of the bytes I read didn't match the size of the xml file I was trying to read.

Then, when I checked the content of the file I was reading, I said it must be a nasty non printable char (\r)  and I checked that with a simple program : the \r were not present.

My question is why fgetc/fgets are ignoring \r and picking only \n and If I want \r to be read how can I proceed ?

Comment: [man fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) , _"If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer."_

Comment: You want a program that reads `\r` characters that *aren't* there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are designed to do so. On the Windows OS the end of line is a combination of two characters `'\n'` (*new line*) and `'\r'` (*carriage return*).

When you open a file with the `"r"` mode these are all converted to `'\n'` so if you are in a Windows OS there will be one character missing from each line.

If you open with the `"rb"` mode, it will no longer convert the two characters to `'\n'` and you will be able to read it. This is the primary difference between the `"b"` and non `"b"` modes.

Note that this freature allows the file to be open by different platforms without caring about this at all, you simply open it in text mode `"r"` or `"w"` for output and don't worry about the way the underlying system represents end of lines.